# Mysql regexp returning zero results

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query which does work:

```
select composition from `drugs` where composition regexp "^Diclofenac([^)])"
```

And the output:

```
Diclofenac(50mg),Thiocolchicoside(8mg)                                              
Diclofenac(50mg),Thiocolchicoside(4mg)                                              
Diclofenac(75mg),Thiocolchicoside(4mg)                                              
Diclofenac(50mg),Thiocolchicoside(4mg)                                              
Diclofenac(50mg),Tamsulosin(0.4mg)                                                  
Diclofenac(50mg),Eperisone(50mg)                                                    
Diclofenac(50mg),Thiocolchicoside(8mg)                                              
Diclofenac(100mg),Rabeprazole(20mg)                                                 
Diclofenac(75mg)                                                                    
Diclofenac(50mg),Thiocolchicoside(8mg)                                              
Diclofenac(50mg),Serratiopeptidase(10mg)                                            
Diclofenac(100mg),Eperisone(150mg)                                                  
Diclofenac(4mg),Thiocolchicoside(50mg)                                              
Diclofenac(100mg),Eperisone(150mg)                                                  
Diclofenac(50mg),Thiocolchicoside(4mg)                                              
Diclofenac(50mg),Thiocolchicoside(8mg)                                              
Diclofenac(50mg),Nimesulide(100mg)                                                  
Diclofenac(50mg),Paracetamol(325mg),Thiocolchicoside(8mg)                           
Diclofenac(NA),Serratiopeptidase(NA)                                                
Diclofenac(50mg),Nimesulide(100mg)                                                  
Diclofenac(50mg),Thiocolchicoside(4mg)                                              
Diclofenac(50mg),Paracetamol(325mg),Thiocolchicoside(4mg)                           
Diclofenac(100mg),Rabeprazole(20mg)                                                 
Diclofenac(50mg),Serratiopeptidase(10mg)                                            
Diclofenac(50mg),Nimesulide(100mg)
```

I want to search for drugs where composition begins with Diclofenac() followed by "," followed by Thiocolchicoside(). Tried following but gives zero results.

```
select composition from `drugs` where composition regexp "^Diclofenac([^)]),Thiocolchicoside([^)])"
```

Edit:
Created DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fkQkn2WKdax2KbZqt7rPQ/0

Comment: Those parentheses probably need to be escaped with backslashes: select composition from `drugs` where composition regexp "^Diclofenac\\([^)]\\),Thiocolchicoside\\([^)]\\)"

Comment: Didn't work :-(

Comment: [^)] merely says match any character, which is not ')'. Since you want to match multiple characters, you should say '[^)]+' . "+" means match 1 or more characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select composition from `drugs` where composition regexp "^Diclofenac\\([^)]+\\),Thiocolchicoside\\([^)]+\\)$"
```

Apart from adding '+' to match multiple non-right brace characters, i.e. [^)], you need to escape '(', because it has a special meaning in regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `^Diclofenac(.*,Thiocolchicoside\(.*\))`

`.*,` means that anything before `,`

`\(.*\)` means (anything in brackets)

Comment: I am assuming you meant ^Diclofenac\(.*\),Thiocolchicoside\(.*\). ".*" is greedy . It also selects following, for example: Diclofenac(50mg),Paracetamol(325mg),Thiocolchicoside(8mg)